# Display only the QR image created with phonegap Barcodescanner Zxing based Plugin

Tags: cordova, zxing, barcode-scanner, oracle-maf

I am using the phonegap barcodescanner plugin from https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner

I am encoding a text string and would like to display only the generated image. Right now I'm using the following code

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(
            "TEXT_TYPE",
            strToEncode,
            function(success) {
                console.log("Encoding succeeded");
                alert("Encode success: " + success);
            },                 
            function(fail) {
                console.log("Encoding failed");
                alert("Encode failed: " + fail);
            }
        );
```

The success object in the alert returns a image with the encoded text below it. I would like to instead get and show only an image object from the result. Is there such a function like **success.toBitmap** or something like that? Or is there an alternative way I could do it?

N.B. I'm actually using this in an Oracle MAF application, so if there are some MAF specific answers it would be great too. Code is as below

```
<amx:verbatim id="v1">
     <![CDATA[
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/barcodescanner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function generateBarcodeFromJavaBean(strToEncode) {
        console.log("Entering generateBarcodeFromJavaBean");
        window.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(
            "TEXT_TYPE",
            strToEncode,
            function(success) {
                console.log("Encoding succeeded");
                alert("Encode success: " + success);
            },                 
            function(fail) {
                console.log("Encoding failed");
                alert("Encode failed: " + fail);
            }
        );
    }

    </script>
]]>
</amx:verbatim>
```

Comment: Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and worked it out doing this:

**First: I inspected the object to know what he returned**

```
alert(JSON.stringify(success,null,4));
```

He returned two [properties](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp): format and file (which had the src of the image).

**Second and last: I appended the image to my div**

```
document.getElementById("QRCode").innerHTML = '<img src="' +
success.file + '" />';
```

And that's it. Hope it works for you too!